# EdgesGeometry not displaying anything?

Tags: three.js

I have a geometry object which looks like this:

[image]

[image]

I am trying to do the following to create a single complete edge around the geometry:

```
var edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( pointsOfIntersection );
var line = new THREE.LineSegments( edges, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000 } ) );
scene.add(line);
```

However this code results in nothing. I'm new to three.js so sorry if I'm making a rookie mistake.

[image]

Comment: Is `.faces` property of the original geometry empty?

Comment: @prisoner849 it is, yes.

Comment: `THREE.EdgesGeometry()` needs a geometry with faces.

Comment: @prisoner849 Any suggestion on how I can take my Vector3 vertices and connect them along via straight lines along the edges?

Comment: Find a library that can do such stuff.